# Is there a reason for verbose boolean evaluation?

Tags: c#, algorithm, boolean, return-value

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Boolean types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752335/boolean-types)

There are times when you want to conditionally set a bool to true or false, but otherwise just to leave it alone. But many times, you do want to set it to either true or false, based on the state of this and/or that. I've often wondered why, in this latter case, most people seem to write code like this (even in books):

```
if ((location < Platypi.Length) && (Platypi[location] != null))
{
  return true;
}
else
{
  return false;
}
```

When this would be just as clear and more concise:

```
return ((location < Platypi.Length) && (Platypi[location] != null));
```

Is being verbose really the preferred method? To me, it borders on being a code smell.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to write the first version.

Comment: The first version says a lot about the insecure feeling of the programmer regarding elementary logic -- this makes me sad. You can (and should) safely assume that any half decent programmer will understand the second version.

Comment: It could be dregs left from debugging or some earlier more complex implementation.  The compiler is likely to produce the same optimized code in any case.  I usually try to clean up that sort of thing.

Comment: Maybe the programmer is planning, in the near future, to extend one branch.

Comment: Sometimes, you're not writing code for yourself, but for future maintainers.  (Although this example is a little extreme.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no reason to do that except to make the flow of the code explicitly clear. Personally, I would write it as:

```
return location < Platypi.Length && Platypi[location] != null;
```

though, because I find it just as easy to understand as the expanded version. Some people might get thrown off by it, though.

Or, it could just be a mistake people make occasionally.

Comment: Prefer this one without the brackets